# Strange output when running a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, types

I have the following statements:

```
const double s=1529340.57;
double f=1-1/1200;
for(j=1;j<=384;j++){
    printf("Age %3d month %2d you have $%.2lf\n", (j+816) / 12, (j+816)%12, s*pow(f,j-1)-4000*((pow(f,j-1)-f)/(f-1)-1));
}
```

and I'm expecting to have the following results:

```
Age  68 month  1 you have $1526615.02
Age  68 month  2 you have $1523887.20
Age  68 month  3 you have $1521157.11
```

and so on.

But, I obtained the following output:

```
Age  68 month  1 you have $-1.#J
Age  68 month  2 you have $-1.#J
Age  68 month  3 you have $-1.#J
```

Do you know why?
Thanks!

Comment: `f=1-1/1200` is like `f=1`

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me, please, any hint how to obtain this value?

Comment: It's late here, so I may be getting it wrong, but should 68 yr 1 month be 1529340.57? That's what I get at least and all I've changed is to make more of the arithmetic explicitly floating-point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `double f=1-1/1200.0;`. As Jean-François Fabre already mentioned 1-1/1200 is not intepreted as double in your version of code. The 1200.0 forces the compiler to handle your formular as decimal.